# Python flask session per user and their own object

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm hopeful someone can point me at the proper way to implement this situation.

I'm building a flask app for multiple concurrent users. The app essentially wraps a back-end RESTful service that requires authentication and will allow commands to be sent. The users do not need to login the flask app itself, but they do provide credentials that I use to authenticate an object to the Restful service. As such, each user needs their own unique object for their particular session. For ease of use/laziness I'm also storing some trivial information in a few `session['x']` variables.

The session information is not unique to each user and it appears the last user to "login" clobbers the previous users' authentication object.

What is the proper way to build this? I could move the `session` variables into the object, but that still leaves the problem that all users require their own back-end object. Do I need to implement a true flask-login?

Comment: You'll need to show some code. I'm not sure how you are persisting the authentication object between requests - are you storing it in the session? What you should be doing is recreating it for each request depending on the unique data from the session.

Comment: I have the object persisted as a global variable across the app itself. (which I know is bad). I'd rather not re-authenticate every request as it's sort of expensive time-wise. I can't persist the object into `session`, so I guess that is the real question: how to persist the object per user-session.

Comment: Well I don't see how you can. The only places to store user-specific stuff is in the session or the db. But if this is a REST API presumably they are using something like OAuth, which should accept a token rather than having to re-authenticate each time.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks. This means I may need to re-engingeer everything out of the object and simply hang onto the tokens and URLs and pass to external functions. I'm not keen on that, but will go down this route if no viable answers come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension in the past to implement login and session management systems.

One issue with storing user information in a python object like session is that you will never be able to scale your application beyond one process. In almost all cases you will want to have more than one process handling requests. Each process will be running with its own python interpreter and will not share the session object. You really want a database that is shared by all processes to store session information, redis works great for this purpose.

For flask-login you need to implement a [user class](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class) and two functions (best implemented as methods of the user class):

- A login function that will authenticate the provided username and password against your service and then generate a large random number (16-32 bytes) using a [cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) (i.e. `os.urandom()`) to use as a session id. Use the generated session id as the key to the user's session information in a sessions table or database and as the id of your User class. The login function should return your User object. I normally implement it as a classmethod of the User class.
- A load_user callback that will take a session id generated in the above function and return the class representing your user populated with information from the database that is storing your session information

Flask-login will handle securely storing (as a HMAC) your session id on the user's computer as a cookie and at the beginning of requests it will call your load_user callback to retrieve the user's information. Logged in users' information will be available by importing the current_user proxy from flask_login (`from flask_login import current_user`). This object is also available in jinja templates.

Comment: Thanks, I'll need a couple days to see if I can implement this.

Comment: Cool, let me know if you have any questions